# C++ overwriting data in a file at a particular position

Tags: c++, file-io

i m having problem in overwriting some data in a file in c++. the code i m using is

```
 int main(){
   fstream fout;
   fout.open("hello.txt",fstream::binary | fstream::out | fstream::app);
   pos=fout.tellp();
   fout.seekp(pos+5);
   fout.write("####",4);
   fout.close();
   return 0;
```

}

the problem is even after using seekp ,the data is always written at the end.I want to write it at a particular position.
And if i dont add fstream::app , the contents of the file are erased.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact position of the data you want to overwrite?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is with the `fstream::app` - it opens the file for appending, meaning all writes go to the end of the file. To avoid having the content erased, try opening with `fstream::in` as well, meaning open with `fstream::binary | fstream::out | fstream::in`.

Comment: but isnt fstream::in for reading from stream ,how will i be able to write to the stream using that?

Comment: If you use both `fstream::in` and `fsteam::out` you'll open the file for reading and writing - meaning it will be opened for writing without deleting the previous content.

Answer (score 5):

You want something like

```
fstream fout( "hello.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary );
fout.seek( offset );
fout.write( "####", 4 );
```

`fstream::app` tells it to move to the end of the file before each output operation, so even though you explicitly seek to a position, the write location gets forced to the end when you do the `write()` (that is `seekp( 0, ios_base::end );`).

cf. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/open/

Another thing to note is that, since you opened the file with `fstream::app`, `tellp()` should return the end of the file. So `seekp( pos + 5 )` should be trying to move beyond the current end of file position.