# How to go to the beginning of the file in fstream?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I'm practicing file handling. I made a text file and wrote some characters in it, now I want the cursor to go to the beginning of the file and put a character there using seekp.

Here is the code

```
fstream ofile;

char ch = 'g';

ofile.open("test.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

ofile.seekp(0, ios::beg);
ofile.put(ch);

ofile.close();
```

**Expected Result:**
It writes g at the start of file.

**Actual Result:**
It appends g at the end.

I tried removing the ios::app tag but ios::out alone truncates the file before writing anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359702/c-filehandling-difference-between-iosapp-and-iosate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: possible workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300306/c-overwriting-data-in-a-file-at-a-particular-position

Comment: Use `ios::in | ios::out`

Comment: @NeilButterworth That does it! Thanks! :)

Comment: @drescherjm ios::ate truncates the file as well. :-/

Comment: @NathanOliver got it!

Answer (score -1):

See:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open

`std::ios::app  seek to the end of stream before each write`