# Edit Single YAML value without updating the formatting of rest of YAML (YAML CPP)

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I already have a YAML file. I want to just change a single value inside that YAML file. I found yaml-cpp library being used widely for parsing/editing yaml files from c++ code. Is there a way I can update single value and leave the rest of the file untouched?

I have a YAML file like this already. And I just want to update the parameter 'non_ros_map_width'

```
# Config file 
package_name: "auto_mapping_ros"

csv_filepath: "/csv/sequence"

# Non ROS Map Values
non_ros_map_width : 1000
```

I tried runnning using yaml-cpp and updated it from the cpp code and I got this:

```
package_name: !<!> auto_mapping_ros
non_ros_map_height: 1355
csv_filepath: !<!> /csv/sequence
```

The values seem to be intact. I am not sure about the strings. but my comments have disappeared. Is there a way to just update the single value and not touch the rest of the file.

My code snippet:

```
YAML::Node node, _baseNode = YAML::LoadFile(auto_mapping_yaml_path); // gets the root node
_baseNode["non_ros_map_width"] = 1355; // edit one of the nodes
std::ofstream fout(auto_mapping_yaml_path);
fout << _baseNode; // dump it back into the file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the YAML documentation https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2767100:

> Comments are a presentation detail and must not have any effect on the
>   serialization tree or representation graph.

YAML will remove the comments by design.

A solution would be to edit the file manually: [C++ overwriting data in a file at a particular position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300306/c-overwriting-data-in-a-file-at-a-particular-position). But you would also have to parse the file manually.